# ERROR accessing objects that inherit from abstract classes in WF4

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

Is it possible classes that derive from an abstract base class cannot be used in WF4?  I have a library that define several object classes... I'm able to access objects in that library just fine except for objects that inherit from an abstract class.

Each time I reference the abstract class or any other classes in its inheritance chain, I get the following error:
"Compiler error(s) encountered processing expression "cust.DisplayName".  'cust' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level."

In this case 'cust' is an instance of a CustomerAccount class which inherits from an AccountEntity (abstract) class which in turn inherits from a BaseEntity (abstract) class...

I can do the following in a C# console application and it works just fine:

```
    CustomerAccount cust = new CustomerAccount();
    cust.DisplayName = "John Doh";
    Console.WriteLine("Out Put: " + ((iSvrBaseEntity)cust).DisplayName);
    Console.WriteLine("Entity Type: " + cust.entityType);
```

But in the WF4 designer, I'm allowed to instantiate Cust and I'm allowed to assign another object to cust... but when I try to access a property in cust (or assign a value to one of it's properties, the error occurs.

Has anyone encountered this?  Is it by design that WF4 doesn't deal with such inheritance?  Is there a workaround?...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Types used need to be public but other than that any normal .NET type should work just fine.

Comment: Thanks! I just tried moving the same code to a new workflow and it worked fine.  Strange thing is that I still get that error in the existing workflow which I'd modified after change the class library containing those objects.  I've noticed from time to time that I get these strange errors in WF4 that mysteriously resolve themselves if I start over or use a different workflow, etc.  It usually happens with ENUMS though... if I change a Enum definition and its referenced in a Flowchart Switch, it'll never work again.  Is that normal?